# Finding a $k$-subset which maximizes a matrix sum

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, combinatorial-optimization

Let $M\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be a given matrix and $k\ge 2$ be a given integer. Then my question is the following optimization problem:

Is there a polynomial-time solution to the following problem: $$S^\star = \arg\max_{\substack{S\subset [N]:\\ |S|\le k}} \sum_{i,j\in S}M_{ij}?$$

This seems to be hard in general (that is, it requires exponential time-complexity), but I could not find a direct link to any known problem. I first thought that this problem is related to the maximum subset problem, but I am not sure. It will be really helpful if somebody can provide any reference to any related problem. It seems that approximate solutions can be found for this problem, but I was unable to find that too after a Google search. It will be really great if someone can give any reference.

Comment: asked simultaneously on TCS stack exchange https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50564/finding-the-best-k-subset-which-maximizes-a-matrix-sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the 0-1 [quadratic knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_knapsack_problem), which is NP-hard.  The binary decision variables $x_i$ indicate whether $i\in S$, and the knapsack capacity is $k$.

You can solve it via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i<j$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ represent $x_i x_j$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i M_{i,i} x_i + \sum_{i<j} (M_{i,j}+M_{j,i}) y_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
y_{i,j} &\le x_i &\text{for $i<j$} \tag1 \\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j &\text{for $i<j$} \tag2 \\
y_{i,j} &\ge x_i + x_j - 1 &\text{for $i<j$} \tag3 \\
\sum_i x_i &\le k \tag4
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $y_{i,j} \implies x_i$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_{i,j} \implies x_j$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $(x_i \land x_j) \implies y_{i,j}$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $|S| \le k$.

If $M_{i,j} \ge 0$, you can omit $(3)$, which will naturally be satisfied because of the objective.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference! Do you know if there is any approximation algorithm for this problem?